# What does the set $\{z \in W: |z| < i, d(z,\mathbb{R}^n-W) > 1/i \}$ mean in partition of unity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology

I am reading a proof about partition of unity in Pollack Guillemin and he introduced this set in the title.

So let the set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and denote any covering of $X$ by $(U_\alpha)$. The sets $U_\alpha$ is open in $X$ so say $U_\alpha = X \cap W_\alpha.$ They set $W = \cup_\alpha W_\alpha$ and let $(K_j)$ be a nested sequence of compact sets that exhaust the set $W$, $\cup_j K_j = W$ and $K_{j} \subset int (K_{j+1})$

Then they write "for instance" $K_i = \{x \in X: |x| < i, d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-X) \geq 1/i \}.$ How do I interpret these sets? I can't figure out what they are suppose to look like. I know what $|x| < i$ means, it means $B_i(0).$ (thanks for correction)

I cannot visualize what combining $|x|<i$ with $d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-X) \geq 1/i$ are doing, are these also points that can get closer points outside the set $X$?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing some pictures? (Also, if we want $K_i$ compact, the $<$ should be a $\le$.)

Comment: Yeah I have tried drawing some pictures, but none of them could make sense since I don't understand what $K_i$ is supposed to look like.

Comment: There’s a typo in the proof - it should be $|z| \leq j$ in $K_j$’s definition, otherwise the set isn’t guaranteed to be compact.

Comment: Think about distance to the boundary of $X$.

Comment: OKay so since on the boundary we are barely touching the complement $R^n - W$ (sorry I switched notations in the title), the condition $d(z, R^n - W) \geq 1/i$ should mean being as far away from the boundary as possible too. So this is the set of all points that do not go near the boundary. How do I combine this with $|z| < i$? Is this just the set of points in the ball of radius $i$ that do not touch the boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in M$ and $A\subseteq M$. The distance from $x$ to $A$ is defined as $$d(x,A)=inf\{d(x,y):y\in A\}$$ Returning to your case, $d(x,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus X)\geq\frac{1}{i}$ means that for each $y\notin X$, $d(x,y)\geq \frac{1}{i}$. This can be seen as isolating each $x\in X$ with a ball of radius $\frac{1}{i}$.

Note: In paragraph 3 you say that you read the first condition as $B_i(x)$, but it is actually $B_i(0)$, maybe it was a typo, but is better to be sure.

Here is a picture i drawed of the situation, in it there is a part of $X$ which is a distance $1/i$ from the border of $X$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was probably a bad idea for me to use $X$ when the proof uses $W.$ So $d(x,y) \geq 1/i$ is purposely missing the boundary of $X$ is how I visualize this?

Comment: Yes, it can be interpreted in that manner.

Comment: Is this set possible to draw? Am I looking at points near the boundary of a ball (circle) that get close to the boundary of $X$?

Comment: I edited the answer to include such a picture as i could draw.